# Java socket with http multipart formdata POST method

Tags: java, sockets, http, multipart

I'm using java and I'm looking for solution to get respond from website.
The problem is i need to create a handshake with server for about 30 sec and then send header and body to finish request.This also a multipart/formdata POST method.
can anyone suggest me where to find tutorial or some example of code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely work lower-level (TCP-level) blocking-style as in http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/socket/send-http-post-request-with-socket/

I'm confident there should be a way to do that in Netty, you could try having a look at [How to send a request with POST parameters in Netty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666891/how-to-send-a-request-with-post-parameters-in-netty).

I couldn't find other Java libraries that would allow you to wait before sending headers, but many (including JDK's URLConnection) will allow you to pre-configure headers and then stream the body.